# Materializecss Select + angularjs

Tags: angularjs, materialize

I have this bug that I can't find and I don't know how to fix.
I searched how to make the materializecss select work with angularjs.
this is the code I found.

```
function materialSelect($timeout) {
            var directive = {
                link: link,
                restrict: 'E',
                require: '?ngModel'
            };

            function link(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

                $timeout(create);
                if (ngModel) {
                    ngModel.$render = create;
                }

                function create() {
                    element.material_select();
                }

                //if using materialize v0.96.0 use this
                element.one('$destroy', function () {
                    element.material_select('destroy');
                });


            }

            return directive;
        }
```

But Now, there's bug in every select I have.
[image]
Sometimes, the select is only 1. the first select don't have any value. the options are inserted in 2nd select. sometimes there's only 1 select and We're praying for that to always happen. When I first used angularjs there's no bug like that. but now that our system is near in completion, that bug shows up

```
    <select id="cREmp123" ng-model="vm.selEmployee"
ng-options="employee.strEmpFirstName for employee in vm.employeeList">
<option value="" selected>Choose...</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Try it without ng-option. That's what I did.

Comment: but it is not possible to pass the whole object using ng-repeat in select

Comment: I had the same problem and I just hardcoded the values into it, I know this is not a helpful advice but sometimes we just want to get something done right ?