# AngularJS Select option using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to pass the who object using ng-repeat in options? 
Example:

```
<select id="cREmp123" ng-model="vm.selEmployee">
 <option value="" selected>Choose...</option>
<option ng-repeat="emp in vm.employeeList" value="vm.employeeList[$index]">{{emp.strEmpFirstName}}</option>
</select>
```

I tried this also

```
<select id="cREmp123" ng-model="vm.selEmployee">
 <option value="" selected>Choose...</option>
<option ng-repeat="emp in vm.employeeList" value="{{emp}}">{{emp.strEmpFirstName}}</option>
</select>
```

I hope somebody will answer me.
I tried using ng-options and it doesn't solve my problem

Comment: The second one should work. But, try to use `value="{{emp.Id}}"`. Where Id is a property that identify your employee. Then, your `vm.selEmployee` will be filled with this value.

Comment: that's the problem sir. I want to pass the whole employee. if employee 1 is selected. then the whole info about employee 1 will be inside the value of that option

Comment: if you trying to set index of the option then  just use value ="{{$index}}" in first example

Comment: ng-options should work why you could not success with it?

Comment: yeah, can you tell us what error you're getting?

Comment: It's just a test. I'm not sure if `value` can be a json value. If it works, you just retrieve the emp from your list, based on your id.

Comment: I'm still trying ng-options. I will study it more. thanks for replies guys

Comment: I have another question. But it is not about ng-repeat. but it is about select options. I've just posted it while ago but no one answers me. so maybe I can ask you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39647390/materializecss-select-angularjs

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ng-options?

Sample code for your reference

```
     <select id="cREmp123" ng-model="selEmployee" 
ng-options="employee as employee.strEmpFirstName for employee in employeeList">
      <option value="" disabled selected>- Please Choose -</option>
    </select>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uovcs2dr/

Comment: thanks. I tried ng-options. maybe I need more practice in using ng-options.